# ArrayList iterator.remove() inside AsyncHttpClient throws IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator, asynchttpclient

I am trying to do HttpClient POST to submit each item of an ArrayList one by one to the server. Here are some snippets of my codes:

```
    ArrayList<String> testArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    testArrayList.add("Item 1");
    testArrayList.add("Item 2");

    final Iterator<String> iterator = testArrayList.iterator();

     while(iterator.hasNext()){

            for(int i = 0; i<testArrayList.size(); i++){
                 currentContent += "| " + testArrayList.get(i) + " | ";
            }

        currentItem = iterator.next();  

        final String url = "some url here"

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.add("item_name", currentItem);

        new AsyncHttpClient().post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler( {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Removing..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                iterator.remove();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is `iterator.remove()` will always throw IllegalStateException. It doesn't happen if AsyncHttpClient is not involved. What I've tried:

- I've tried putting `iterator.next()` within `onSuccess()` (no `RequestParams` added in this case, just to try it out) but it
  causes the app to stuck and not responding. (In my case I actually
  would like to keep it outside `onSuccess()` because from the iterator
  is where I will retrieve my `RequestParams`)
- I've searched for similar questions. Most of the problems are caused by not calling `iterator.next()` before `iterator.remove()`. I have it but my code is still not working. Another frequent cause would be the `iterator.remove()` is called within an inner loop, but that is not my case.

I've been stuck at this problem for weeks. Please help me out.

Comment: Why you are doing all Async calls inside `while(iterator.hasNext())` ? `iterator.remove()` inside `onSuccess` is causing the problem . Since its an Asynchronous call thats why `iterator.remove()` is throwing `IllegalStateException` You should look for a elegant way to do this.

Comment: @ADM I am sorry for my unelegant way as I am still learning android. What i'm thinking is: after successfully sending the arraylist by HTTP POST, I want it to be removed from the arraylist. That's why `remove()` is called inside `onSuccess`. What other way can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a recursion where the method calls itself.

```
 ArrayList<String> testArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        testArrayList.add("Item 1");
        testArrayList.add("Item 2");    


    void submitItem(ArrayList<String> items){

    final String url = "some url here"

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.add("item_name", currentItem);

 new AsyncHttpClient().post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler( {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] 
             responseBody) {


                items.remove(0);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Removing..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(ites.size() > 0) submitItem(items);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });

}
```

Comment: This actually does the trick. Thank you very much! I've read so much about using arraylist.remove(index) is not very safe with loops but I've never thought of recursion as an alternative.

Comment: This should work. However, there is an implication of this solution: only single item will be posted at a time. It also does not solve the reliability issue with your design, the "what if my app gets killed" problem.

Answer (score 4):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--:

`IllegalStateException` - if the next method has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method

You call iterator.remove() from a callback passed to `AsyncHttpClient`. That client executes on a different `Thread` and callback will be executed on the main UI `Thread`. However you have no guarantees about the order of execution here.

So what probably happens time-wise is:
1) `iterator.next()` (from the while loop)
2) post triggered
3) `iterator.next()` (from the while loop)
4) post triggered
5) first callback `iterator.remove()`
6) second callback `iterator.remove()`

You can try to verify it by putting log statements before call to next and remove.

Comment: I've added some log statements and yes, you are right. Thank you. However, I still can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: @tyn, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to remove the items from the ArrayList in the first place?

Comment: The actual ArrayList contains data to be POSTed once internet connection is available. What I'm trying to do was: 1) check if there is internet connection, 2) if there is internet connection, POST data inside ArrayList if any, 3) upon successful submission (`onSuccess`), remove the POSTed item from the ArrayList. Think of it as an ArrayList containing pending data created while offline which are to be submitted once device is conected to the internet.

Comment: ArrayList does not seem to be a right choince here as it is kept in memory. What if your app gets killed by OS before internet connection is available? Probably chosing SQLite or some other persistent store will be a better option. Then the solution to your problem will depend on the option you will choose.

Comment: I'm actually using Shared Preference to store the ArrayList as JSON string. Whenever I need to retrieve/save the data, I need to parse the JSON string into ArrayList. I've been reading on SQLite implementation as well and this gives me more reason to actually implement it. Thank you very much.